# Why can't I replace the movie clip in this example with another?

Tags: flash

http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/print_screen/page002.php

In this code, if I replace the movie clip with a different one, it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Code:

```
function print_me(){
    video_mc.pause()    // first pause the playing video
    pn = new PrintScreen(); // initialize the PrintScreen class
    pn.addListener( listener ); // assign a listener
    pn.print(_root, 0, 0, 500, 210) // copy the _root
    loader.label = "computing... 0%"
    loader.open(true, true, true);  // open a loader
}
```

This calls the movie clip, but when I replace it with any other movie clip, it does not call the PHP.

```
listener.onComplete = function(target:MovieClip, load_var:LoadVars){
    loader.label = "sending to php..."
    load_var.send("files/pixels.php", "_blank", "POST")
    loader.close()
}
```

I feel something is missing or I am not able to understand correctly what the author is trying to explain.

Comment: The title on your question is terrible.

Comment: In addition to nsander's comment, I question whether this is an actual question....

Comment: The title is the least of the problems.

Comment: what else is the suitable title...

Comment: @Theband: I edited in a slightly better title. Your question is unanswerable. Post the code you are having the problem with and tell us what the error is. What you did here is ridiculous.

Answer (score -1):

video_mc.pause() this is a simple pause on your move clip

what your code is cause script alone from that page doesn't tell much about your problem